# Search Array of Strings in Array of String, receive Int-Array of indexes

Tags: java

I'm looking for an lib which can search an array of strings with multible search-strings (array). I want to get an int-array of all indexes/matches.

```
private int[] getIndexArray(String[] pArray, String[] pSearchStrings) {
    int[] indexes = new int[0];
    for (String str : pArray) {
        if (ArrayUtils.contains(pSearchStrings, str))
            indexes = ArrayUtils.add(indexes, ArrayUtils.indexOf(pArray, str));
    }
    return indexes;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `pSearchStrings[]` for all `pArray[]`, you can transform `pSearchStrings` in a *Pattern* and use *matcher* method to avoid to load each time *ArrayUtils.contains(..)*

**EDIT**

```
private static int[] getIndexArray(String[] pArray, String[] pSearchStrings) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((int) estimateSizeOfSearchStrings +16);
    for (String searh : pSearchStrings) {
         sb.append(".*");
         sb.append(search)
         sb.append(".*|");
    }
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(sb.toString().subString(0,sb.length() -1);
    // If pSearchStrings are always the same, you can put static 'patt' outside this method
    // Or pass pre-compiled 'patt' as a parameter.
    int [] indexes = new int [pSearchStrings.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (String str : pArray) {
            if (patt.matcher(str).find())
            indexes[i++] = ArrayUtils.indexOf(pArray, str);
    }
    return indexes;
}
```

Comment: Interesting point of view. But is it really a better way of checking to create a pattern and check the pattern instead of calling `ArrayUtils.contains(..)`. Both methods will run in O(n), but the creation of the pattern will cost performance and memory.

Comment: @d.poellath As I wrote in comment, if you can put `patt`in a static field outside the method, or have determined Pattern to pass as parameter, it certainly will give more maintanble code. I'm not certain that a `foreach` with `ArrayUtils.indexOf()` will be needed if you use a fr(int i = 0, n = `pArray.length; ...)`

Comment: I have to correct my comment before. The methods both will need O(n*m), because of the two arrays. In your method the search-array of size m will be transformed to an string of sitze m*(size(searchStr)). there is no really time saving. especially because the you need to create a pattern for every different search array (and store for reuse). or do i miss something?

Comment: @d.poellath Usign pattern(s) is useful only if you can built it(them) at the begining, and know all matching cases ; then pass it(them) as a parameter. If `getIndexArray` is uses three or more times on big `[]pArray`, it may be worst to test the two methods . But I guess the gain is less than 1%, compile tools are too powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private static int[] getIndexArray(String[] pArray, String[] pSearchStrings) {
    //There can only be as many indices as there are search terms, right? So:
    int [] indexes = new int [pSearchStrings.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (String str : pArray) {
            if (ArrayUtils.contains(pSearchStrings, str))
            indexes[i++] = ArrayUtils.indexOf(pArray, str);
    }
    return indexes;
}
```

I haven't tested it, so I dunno if it works, but your code makes a new array every time through the loop (which isn't that big of a deal, but still).